# SQL code to copy data from 1 database table to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, data-transfer

I have messed up the data. I have been ammended ids and values to the point where i cannot remember what the originals were. (testing a few things).

I have a table called `query_string_interpretation` and its part of the DB called, test1_db

I have a backup database which i have restored called, test2_db

How can I restore its contents from one database table to another?

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? Also, which version of SQL 2008? or 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you need to be sure that you have all your data in source table, or data is placed in both tables - source and destination. In first case you need to truncate the destination table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE test1_db..query_string_interpretation
```

Second, you need to be sure that you will insert the right values into IDENTITY fields, if these fields exists. Use `SET INDENITY_INSERT ON` statement. 
Third, you need to insert the values:

```
insert into test1_db..query_string_interpretation
select * from test2_db..query_string_interpretation
```

And don't forget to switch the `INDENITY_INSERT` to OFF, you you switched it to ON in the second step.

Comment: @sp-1986, what does `and you are polite` have to do with SQL?

Comment: Patronizing replies are not friendly or welcoming for new members. To answer your question, nothing - but i was being friendly.

Comment: @sp-1986, perhaps something was deleted, but when I read everything, I see nothing even close to rude.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information on your part...generally you can use `INSERT INTO/SELECT FROM` to move data between tables.

The syntax is roughly:

```
INSERT INTO
test1_db..query_string_interpretation ( <your columns here>)
select <your columns here>
FROM test2_db..query_string_interpretation
```

Comment: do i not need to truncate my first table?

Comment: I just deleted the first table contents and then ran it with *

Comment: Your question is so vague that it is tough to know what exactly you need.  Truncate? maybe; Delete probably. I can't make a reccomendation b/c I don't know if there are foreign keys preventing deletion, what the table structure looks like, if test2 contains an exact copy of the data in test1, if they are the same server, or anything.  You question just asks how to write the data from test2 back to test1. I assumed you understood how to clear out your table.  Spend more time writing your questions and you'll get more precise answers.

Comment: Glad * worked, but without knowing if your table had an identity column I couldn't assume that * was OK.

Comment: I just saw your comment to another poster.  Sorry if it came across rude, I didn't intend to.  My comment was terse, but that's because we're character limited.  I saw that you haven't posted here a lot and wanted to point out various pieces of information you could have included in your question.  The better you ask your question the more precise answers can be.  For example, no guessing about an identity column in your table, or FK's that would prevent a simple DELETE * FROM.

Comment: Yes i did take it the wrong way. But thank you for setting your record straight. The air has been cleared. Best Regards sp-1986

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SQL wizard to do this for you. In Management Studio, right click on either database, select `Tasks` then `Import Data...` or `Export Data...`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
delete from test1_db..query_string_interpretation

insert into test1_db..query_string_interpretation
select * from test2_db..query_string_interpretation
```

if you have an identity field you may have to write the name of the columns (except for the identity one). if you need to keep the IDs, take a look at the SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: SET INDENTITY INSERT ON, maybe?